# Best way to convert OpenWeather API from Kelvin to fahrenheit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { fetchWeather } from './api/fetchWeather';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});
    
    const search = async (e) => {
        if(e.key === 'Enter') {
            const data = await fetchWeather(query);

            setWeather(data);
            setQuery('');
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="main-container">
            <input type="text"className="search"placeholder="Search..."value={query}onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}onKeyPress={search}/>
            {weather.main && (
                <div className="city">
                    <h2 className="city-name">
                        <span>{weather.name}</span>
                        <sup>{weather.sys.country}</sup>
                    </h2>
                    <div className="city-temp">
                        {Math.round(weather.main.temp)}  
                        <sup>&deg;F</sup>
                    </div>
                    <div className="info">
                        <img className="city-icon" src={`https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${weather.weather[0].icon}@2x.png`} alt={weather.weather[0].description} />
                        <p>{weather.weather[0].description}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

What would be the best way to convert the Openweather API from Kelvin to Fahrenheit or celcius? Do I create a formula on the {Math.round(weather.main.temp)} line or do I create a new function that converts it for me?

Comment: both of these seem fine :) if you're looking for style pointers or guidance on how to structure your code for readibility/extensibility, check out [SE.Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)! Stack overflow is here if you have a specific problem you want us to debug :)

Comment: oh yeah sorry about that! check out the {stack-exchange-site.com}/help/on-topic  pages, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for a guide to what each site considers appropriate for that site. good luck!

Comment: Its been a pain on stack exchange and wont let me ask the question.       I appreciate it!

Comment: no problem. fair warning, code review is less popular and also has their own https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic guidelines. In general, questions like "I would like guidance structuring my project" are going to be harder to get answers to, because that's really the tough part that requires experience and training, and the right answer will depend on the context. for that I'd find open source projects to use as a model and just keep learning! good luck!

Comment: Worth noting that on CR, you should have implemented your code the best you can, and present _full, working code_, rather than asking for implementations of missing functionality.  Particularly relevant here (with a choice of implementations): you can provide two different versions that both work; there's a tag ([comparative-review](//codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-review)) for that.